# Filling a matrix with a series of other matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to fill a matrix with a series of other matrices in the same way that 'mat' is formatted in my example (where m1 and m2 are the matrices being used to fill mat). Does anyone know if there is a function that does this?

```
m1 <- matrix (1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
m2 <- matrix (2, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
```

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/17495841?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `bdiag` function from the `Matrix` package. The surrounding `as.matrix` converts it back to a base matrix, rather than a `dgCmatrix`.

```
library(Matrix)
as.matrix(bdiag(list(m1, m2)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    2    2    2
[4,]    0    0    2    2    2
[5,]    0    0    2    2    2
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for that!